# Proper way to install Nginx on Ubuntu 15.10 after compiling myself

Tags: nginx, systemd, ubuntu-15.10

I just compiled the latest version of Nginx on Ubuntu 15.10 and installed it using

```
dpkg -i nginx_1.9.15-1_amd64.deb
```

However, the systemd service script was not created so nginx is not running.  How exactly do I do this and what are the proper steps to install nginx after self-compiling so that all of the necessary files are present and in their proper locations?

Thanks!

Comment: You know that nginx has pre-compiled packages, right? https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/installing-nginx-open-source/

Comment: Yes, thank you, but I needed to add the Perl module which doesn't come in the standard configuration.

Comment: There is nginx PPA. Use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not compile nginx yourself unless you absolutely must. In your case there are two possibilities:

1. Use [NGINX Mainline PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/ubuntu/development).

   To use PPA, execute commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nginx/development
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nginx-extras
   ```
2. Since 1.9.11 Nginx supports dynamic modules and they have [nginx-module-perl](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#dynmodules).

   To use nginx's official repository create file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list` with following lines (`wily` is codename for Ubuntu 15.10):

   ```
   deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ wily nginx
   deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ wily nginx
   ```

   and execute commands:

   ```
   wget -qO - http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | sudo apt-key add -
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nginx nginx-module-perl
   ```

Comment: How would I download and install the dynamic perl module?

Comment: It's in the same repo. But you should not download files manually, instead you hould add nginx's repo and use apt-get/aptitude.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to find this out myself but Google is not my friend today.  What are the exact steps needed to install nginx and the perl module?  I tried "sudo apt-get install nginx nginx-module-perl" but I get an error message that the perl module (by that name) doesn't exist.

Comment: Installation instructions are on the same pages.

Comment: @Littlebob I've added instructions

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [my tutorial](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/#nginx-source). Here's how I build and install Nginx and a few modules. The key part for you is "make install".

```
cd /home/ec2-user
mkdir nginx-build
cd nginx-build
service nginx stop
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
yum install pcre-devel zlib-devel openssl-devel
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.9.11.tar.gz
wget http://labs.frickle.com/files/ngx_cache_purge-2.3.tar.gz
wget https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module/archive/v0.29.tar.gz
tar -xzf nginx-1.9.11.tar.gz
tar -xzf ngx_cache_purge-2.3.tar.gz
tar -xzf v0.29.tar.gz
tar -xzf 1.9.32.10.tar.gz    # Google Pagespeed, optional
ngx_version=1.9.32.10
wget https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/archive/release-${ngx_version}-beta.zip   # Google Pagespeed, optional
cd ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.10-beta   # Google Pagespeed, optional
wget https://dl.google.com/dl/page-speed/psol/${ngx_version}.tar.gz   # Google Pagespeed, optional
cd ../nginx-1.9.9
# Note that I have no idea what the next line does but it was in the official guide
PS_NGX_EXTRA_FLAGS="--with-cc=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/gcc"
# Safe option, slower, lots of modules included
#./configure --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-threads --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-http_slice_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_v2_module --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --add-module=/tmp/ngx_cache_purge-2.3 --add-module=/tmp/headers-more-nginx-module-0.29 --with-http_realip_module --add-modeule=../ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.10-beta
# Many plugins removed, extra optimisations including some JUST for the machine it's compiled on
./configure --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-threads --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_v2_module --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=native' --add-module=../ngx_cache_purge-2.3 --add-module=../headers-more-nginx-module-0.29 --with-http_realip_module --add-module=../ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.10-beta
make && make install
make clean  (NB: optional)
service nginx start
```