# Compiling nginx 1.11.9 on CentOS 6 with OpenSSL 1.0.2k

Tags: nginx, centos6, openssl

I am running CentOS 6 x64, and I wish to compile nginx 1.11.9 against OpenSSL 1.0.2k so I can make use of HTTP/2.

I've downloaded openssl-1.0.2k to /usr/local/src:

`[root@qpat1 nginx-1.11.9]# ls /usr/local/src
openssl-1.0.2k`

I am attempting to compile nginx using these commands:

`$ ./configure --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --with-openssl=/usr/local/src/openssl-1.0.2k
$ make`

It works for a while and then kicks up:

`` objs/src/mail/ngx_mail_pop3_module.o \
        objs/src/mail/ngx_mail_pop3_handler.o \
        objs/src/mail/ngx_mail_imap_module.o \
        objs/src/mail/ngx_mail_imap_handler.o \
        objs/src/mail/ngx_mail_smtp_module.o \
        objs/src/mail/ngx_mail_smtp_handler.o \
        objs/src/mail/ngx_mail_auth_http_module.o \
        objs/src/mail/ngx_mail_proxy_module.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_variables.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_script.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_handler.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_log_module.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_upstream.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_round_robin.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_write_filter_module.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_module.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_realip_module.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_limit_conn_module.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_access_module.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_geo_module.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_map_module.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_split_clients_module.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_return_module.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_hash_module.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_least_conn_module.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_zone_module.o \
        objs/src/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.o \
        objs/ngx_modules.o \
        -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie -ldl -lpthread -lpthread -lcrypt -lpcre /usr/local/src/openssl-1.0.2k/.openssl/lib/libssl.a /usr/local/src/openssl-1.0.2k/.openssl/lib/libcrypto.a -ldl -lz \
        -Wl,-E
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/src/openssl-1.0.2k/.openssl/lib/libssl.a(s23_meth.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/src/openssl-1.0.2k/.openssl/lib/libssl.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [objs/nginx] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/nginx-http2/nginx-1.11.9'
make: *** [build] Error 2 ``

I have tried about everything I can think of. I have followed instructions I've found for similar issues to compile OpenSSL with -fPIC:

`./config -fPIC
make depend
make
make install`

Nothing seems to be working. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some inspiration from IRC, I discovered that the Makefile generated by nginx's configure script doesn't compile OpenSSL (or any other sources you're using, like zlib) with `-fPIC`. Editing the generated Makefile (objs/Makefile), finding the openssl `./config` command, and adding `-fPIC` to that command line made it compile.

Answer (score 0):

I have instructions on how to build Nginx from source on [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/772864/306795). It was pretty easy. I didn't build OpenSSL, I used a binary.

Comment: I was able to build with no issues without specifying a custom OpenSSL version. Using a different OpenSSL source is what triggered my problem.